# How to get value of selected label from repeater using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

i have bind the the repeater and i want to get the value of label while check on particular check box:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggleCheck').change(function() {
    console.log('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))

    RepeaterData();
  })
})


function RepeaterData() {
  var size = $('.nameLabel').length;
  console.log('size' + size);
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var name = $('.nameLabel').eq(i).text();
    var id = $('.IdLabel').eq(i).text();
    //var result = document.getElementById('result');
    alert(name);
    // result.innerText += name + "  \t " + id + "\n";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCust" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-highlight" data-provide="datatable" data-display-rows="10" data-info="true" data-search="true" data-length-change="true" data-paginate="true">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-filterable="true">No</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" CssClass="IdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id")%>' Style="display: none"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblno" CssClass="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("no")%>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name")%>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Checkbox1" commandname="Edit" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" checked='<%# (Eval("status")).ToString() == "1" ? true : false %>' runat="server" class="toggleCheck">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

i have written above code .

Now when i click on check box then i need to get id of that checkbox using javascript.

I have tried to get the value but it gives me all the value instead of particular id on checkbox checked/unchecked.

How can i get value of particular id when i am checked/unchecked the checkbox ?

Comment: Can you change your ASP code to HTML? As your question doesn't need it. --- Also, you can remove the ASP.net, c#, and .net tags.

Comment: it is a asp.net code. <asp:repeater> and <asp:label> . Please check it.

Comment: Surely it doesn't matter? ... as your question is to do with the output HTML and JS, not the c#/asp.net.

Comment: it is matter because i want to value of  the label from  repeater .

Comment: You can try `$(this).parent().find('.nameLabel').text()`. Idea is to navigate to necessary element using `this`(current element).

Comment: i have tried it but it gives me empty with `this`

Comment: Did you try inside `RepeaterData`? Try to log `this` in console and the check DOM tree

Comment: i have solved. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this...

```
 $('.toggleCheck').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
 })
```

or if you want to identify if cheched...

```
 $('.toggleCheck').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it . Below is the code.

i have added `var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();`
with the above line i am able to get particular id on checkbox checked/unchecked

```
   $(function() {
      $('.toggleCheck').change(function() {
        console.log('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();

      })
    })
```